Regarding the issue of degraded query performance after upgrading bind9
I would like to ask if anyone has encountered a problem where query performance deteriorates after upgrading the bind version. Here are the performance test results for versions 9.16.49, 9.18.25, and 9.12.3-P4:
9.16.49 performance data



Quries
amount




sent
135762


completed
(99.97%) 135719


lost
(0.03%) 43




Response codes: NOERROR 135719 (100.00%)
Average packet size: request 35, response 51
Run time (s):         120.063225
Queries per second:   1130.396089
Average Latency (s):  0.086731 (min 0.001513, max 0.172726)
Latency StdDev (s):   0.019442

9.18.25 performance data



Quries
amount




sent
142300


completed
142300


lost
0




Response codes:       NOERROR 142300 (100.00%)
Average packet size:  request 35, response 51
Run time (s):         120.087726
Queries per second:   1184.967063
Average Latency (s):  0.084285 (min 0.001735, max 0.199955)
Latency StdDev (s):   0.018229

9.12.3-P4 performance data



Quries
amount




sent
1016067


completed
(100.00%) 1016040


lost
(0.00%) 27




Response codes:       NOERROR 1016040 (100.00%)
Average packet size:  request 35, response 51
Run time (s):         120.014670
Queries per second:   8465.965036
Average Latency (s):  0.011652 (min 0.001157, max 0.034407)
Latency StdDev (s):   0.001628

Deployment environment

Operating System: CentOS 7 2009
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-1160.92.1.el7.x86_64
Current Version: BIND 9.12.3-P4 id:a3d2ae0
Tested Versions: BIND 9.16.49 & 9.18.25
Testing Tool: dnsperf
Relevant Test: 5 domains, 120 seconds of queries using the command (dnsperf -d dnstest.txt -s 10.0.3.12 -l 120) for internal domain names

Compilation commands
9.12.3 and 9.16.49
./configure \
    --prefix=/usr/local/named \
    --sysconfdir=/etc/named \
    --with-dlz-mysql \
    --enable-threads \
    --enable-epoll \
    --disable-chroot \
    --enable-backtrace \
    --enable-largefile \
    --disable-ipv6 \
    --with-openssl \
    --with-libxml2

9.18.25
./configure \
    --prefix=/usr/local/named \
    --sysconfdir=/etc/named \
    --disable-chroot \
    --enable-largefile \
    --with-openssl \
    --with-libxml2

All versions have installed contrib/dlz/modules/mysql.
BIND configuration
options {
   listen-on port 53 { any; };
   listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
   directory       "/etc/named";
   allow-query     { any; };
   forward first;
   forwarders { 10.0.3.6; 10.0.0.221; 10.0.0.222; };
   recursion yes;
   max-cache-ttl 30;
};

logging {
   channel default_log {
      file "/var/log/bind/named.log" versions 10 size 200m;
      severity dynamic;
      print-category yes;
      print-severity yes;
      print-time yes;
   };
   channel query_log {
      file "/var/log/bind/query.log" versions 10 size 200m;
      severity dynamic;
      print-category yes;
      print-severity yes;
      print-time yes;
   };
   channel error_query_log {
      file "/var/log/bind/error_query.log" versions 1 size 200m;
      severity dynamic;
      print-category yes;
      print-severity yes;
      print-time yes;
   };
   channel resolver_log {
      file "/var/log/bind/resolver.log" versions 10 size 200m;
      severity dynamic;
      print-category yes;
      print-severity yes;
      print-time yes;
   };
   category default {default_log;};
   category queries {query_log;};
   category query-errors {error_query_log;};
   category resolver {resolver_log;};
   category lame-servers {null;};
   category edns-disabled {null;};
};

dlz "Mysql zone" {
   database "dlopen /usr/lib/bind9/dlz_mysql_dynamic.so
      {host=10.0.3.26 dbname=dns ssl=false port=3306 user=dnsuser pass=aaaaabbbbbccccc threads=50}
      {select zone from dns_records where zone = '$zone$' and  view = 'any' limit 1}
      {select ttl,type,if(mx_priority>0,mx_priority,NULL),case when lower(type)='txt' then concat('\"',data,'\"') when lower(type)    =  'soa'  then   concat_ws(' ',  data,  resp_person,  serial,  refresh,  retry,  expire,  minimum)   else   data   end   as   mydata   from   dns_records where zone = '$zone$'   and host = '$record$' and view = 'any'}";
};


Many, many moons ago ... while running a fleet of BIND9 dns servers, I also noticed this. Based on the compile stuff you posted, you may very well not only recover but gain performance from using GCC compile-time performance optimization? Test it and try it out to see, but I had SIGNIFICANT GAIN.
It's even better if your workload is strictly authoritative answers.
Most compilers use -O2 out of the box. Experiment with the -Ofast macro expansion. Read up on it and decide what's best for your specific environment.
The gains are worth it!!! You may need to go back and recompile your own openss and libxml2 libraries? If you use what is provided in mainline software repositories, they were compiled to work and deliver average performance across a wide variety of similar hardware platforms.
Optimize for the platforms/chipsets that you actually run on and do more than basic optimizations (i.e. -O2).
The differences are immense!!! It's a bit of a pita, but if you remember exactly what you did you can reproduce your efforts with other software as well. The performance improvements are INSANE!
You will look like a superhero to everyone. They will hoist you upon their shoulders and carry you about cheering your name. You will be worthy of a cape for your office chair, at last. There will be much rejoicing. Hooray!
